# can't run or install Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubuntu-netbook, lenovo

Before this I had run ubuntu 10.04 netbook edition on my Lenovo s10-3c but I just figure out ubuntu 10.10 is a newes ubuntu for netbook.So I just download the ISO Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition.But here is my problem I can't run it or install it on my netbook.It's just came out Ubuntu boot logo and  I wait for 10 minutes but nothing happen.Can someone help me in this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu no longer makes the netbook edition because its Unity interface has been included with mainstream Ubuntu, meaning the default Ubuntu is for netbooks, too. It's always recommended to install the latest version of Ubuntu, especially if you're running relatively new hardware. You'll likely have better luck with Ubuntu 11.10 than with 10.10.

Looks like a lot of users reported [that their keyboard doesn't work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/677633) in older versions of Ubuntu (seems to work if you include the `noacpi = off` boot parameter), though you haven't mentioned a keyboard issue. I recommend running Ubuntu 11.10, at least try a live session to see if it works. After installing Ubuntu if Brasero is still installed you can remove it to make it more like the Netbook edition was (unless you're considering burning discs using an external disc drive).

Comment: but I hav try ubuntu 11.10 but it's too roocky for my netbook and otherwise my prosesor fan also spin with more faster not like win7.That why I want to install 10.10 netbook edition

Comment: Dean. If there is no specific reason why you NEED 10.10 then just stick with 10.04. But dont install NB edition, use the normal desktop..its quicker in my experience(I've installed it on a dozen or so netbooks), then add a dock (docky/cairo amongst others).  10.10 is supported only until this april 2012, 10.04 supported to april 2013.

Comment: If the fan is the issue, there are ways of solving that. Found a recent forum thread here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1902644
Seems like a trivial reason not to use the latest Ubuntu, I'm sure you can find an appropriate solution for your netbook easily enough.